How to properly translate this python code to vb.net? The code requires knowing the name of subclass BEFORE calling mybase
The python code is here https://github.com/Polymarket/poly-py-eip712-structs/blob/main/poly_eip712_structs/struct.py
It is a way to define EIP712Struct from basic type
class EIP712Struct(EIP712Type, metaclass=OrderedAttributesMeta):
    """A representation of an EIP712 struct. Subclass it to use it.

    Example:
        from eip712_structs import EIP712Struct, String

        class MyStruct(EIP712Struct):
            some_param = String()

        struct_instance = MyStruct(some_param='some_value')
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EIP712Struct, self).__init__(self.type_name, None)
        members = self.get_members()
        self.values = dict()
        for name, typ in members:
            value = kwargs.get(name)
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                value = typ(**value)
            self.values[name] = value

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.type_name = cls.__name__

Here is the problem with Python code.
In Python you can do
super(EIP712Struct, self).__init__(self.type_name, None)

The equivalent would be calling
MyBase(me.TypeName,nothing)

But in VB.net you can't do that.
Me, doesn't exist yet when you call MyBase.
So how do you get around that?
One way is to do shared function
Protected Shared ReadOnly Property ClassTypeName As String
    Get
        Dim b = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name
        ' This will return the subclass's name, not "EIP712Struct"
        Return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name
    End Get
End Property

But that ClassTypeName end up EIP712Struct and not the name of the subclass.
So how do you do this properly in vb.net?

I think this is a general .NET issue with the initialization model which runs top-down.  The best alternative that I can think of is to have a protected routine on the base class that must be called from the derived ctor after the base has been initialized.  This does mean that you can't enforce it via the base class argument list, and you will have a brief period where the base class doesn't have a valid state for the class type name.

I wonder if this might be an XY problem?  What does the base class need to do with the type name?  Could it just be an abstract property instead?  Or could the curiously recurring generic pattern be used to handle it?

It's not clear to me what this python code is trying to do. It looks like you are trying to make the class expose its metadata or something. You might be better using built-in C# Reflection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/reflection/reflection

I've been thinking that @Craig idea is correct. I just think it's not elegant but it's a chicken and egg problem. To know the class of the new operator you need to have access to Me which is not available during initialization. But we already can know that. The computer already knows. In vb.net this feature is simply not availble.

Is there a reason not to use ready-made .NET code such as Nethereum? Or a search for ".net eip712" shows a couple of GitHub projects. Starting from Python might not be the easiest route.

you think that's a better way?

I am following @Craig's comment. I just don't feel it's elegant.
So I basically add this function
Protected Sub updateTypeName()
    _TypeName = Me.GetType().Name
End Sub

And then I do
Public Sub New(ByVal ParamArray kwargs As EIP712Type())
    MyBase.New("", Nothing) ' Assuming EIP712Type has a constructor like this
    updateTypeName()
    Dim members As List(Of Tuple(Of String, EIP712Type)) = GetMembers()
    values = New Dictionary(Of String, EIP712Type)

So the TypeName is defined as
Public ReadOnly Property TypeName As String

and it's readonly and can only be modified by descendants of EIP712Type and they can only do so by changing the name to the actual name of the class.
If there is a more elegant solution I would like to know.
The issue is VB should already know the type of the class calling new variable. However, unlike in many of other programming language, VB doesn't have a keyword to refer to that class. Me refer to the object. Python usually have self and cls and that has no equivalent in VB.
I maybe missing something.
